# Microsoft 365 Rest API returns Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object when getting versions of a large(8GB) file

Tags: sharepoint-online, version-history

I am using the endpoint `_api/web/GetFileById('" + fileUniqueId + "')/Versions('versionId')` and `_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(path)/Versions('versionId')` to get FileVersion based on fileId/path and version id. Both works on small files, but it return Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object when file is large, in my case it is 8GB. Is this an existing issue in SharePoint or is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, I could reproduce this issue on my end. And I find a same issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55835984/o365-rest-api-error-response-for-version-method

It seems that this is an existing issue that large files in Microsoft Office 365 SharePoint do not support Versions request.